# Do non-"text/javascript" type'd <script> tags block DOMContentLoaded while they download?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, script-tag, head.js

Normally, external-file javascripts block `window`'s `load` and `DOMContentLoaded` events, like, for instance, if we were to have:

```
<script src="http://so.me/file.js"></script>
```

...then the DOM renderer would pause work as `http://so.me/file.js` downloaded and executed.

Now, let's suppose that instead of the above, we have:

```
<script type="not-js" src="http://so.me/file.js"></script>
```

I know that it would download but not execute the resource, but as it downloaded, would the page renderer halt as above, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a [talk on Google I/O 2012](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/207/) from Ryan Fioravanti called Building High Performance Mobile Web Applications where he used this exact technique to download scripts but prevent them from being executed. He would then execute the scripts by appending them to the `DOM`.

See the part where he explains it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jD_-r6y558o&t=19m32s).

He explains that the page rendering time got significantly faster and that was because the JavaScript did not execute and prevent the page rendering procedure.

> would the page renderer halt as above, or not

My answer is no. Maybe someone with more detailed knowledge about browser internals could give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might give it a try, but my guess is that it would.  You could get around this the same way that Google Analytics and Facebook Connect write async script references to the DOM.

For example:

```
<!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
<script>
    var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
    (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
</script>
```

You could use the same approach if you're worried about your script reference blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for: `<script defer="defer"></script>` so that the script doesn't suspend loading the rest of the website?

Comment: Yes, in a way I am, but I'm looking for a hacky way which I know is out there to make it work across different versions of different browsers, some of which won't support @defer.

Comment: To your original question: yes even if you do set the type to something random, the rendering can be halted depending on what browser is running the piece of code. The only way you won't halt execution, is to subscribe to the onload event, and only after that use Landon's solution to dynamically inject the script into your page ..it's the same as doing $(document).ready(callback), or head.ready(callback)

Answer (score 1):

Kernel's solution is probably what you are looking for

you can either use `<script src="http://so.me/file.js" defer></script>` or `<script src="http://so.me/file.js" async></script>`

- defer : load in parallel and execute in order

  - supported in almost all browsers including older versions of IE ..however execution order is not always respected even though it should be..
- async: load in parallel and execute as soon as possible

  - supported in almost all browsers browsers except IE where support was only added in IE10

Landon's solution is the same as using `async`, except you are controlling things programmatically.

...that said, almost all modern browsers will default to the defer method, whether you specify something or not. Try loading a bunch of scripts in a classic manner in FF or Chrome while looking at the waterfall chart in their developer tools (or Fiddler), and you'll see that they load everything in parallel even though you didn't even ask them to :)

Refined solution (should work in any browser):

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>


      <script>
         window.onload = function() {
            var s  =  document.createElement("script");
            s.type = "text/javascript";
            s.src  = "http://so.me/file.js";

            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Then again if you're willing to do this, you can just as well stick your scripts at the end of your document right before `</body>`.

**Anything** you stick in your `<head>` or before `</body>` will cause rendering to halt, but that doesn't mean it's a problem ..a page is rendered from top to bottom, so once you get to `</body>` even if `onload` hasn't fired yet, your page **is** already visible to the end user.

Comment: However you are probably right about the ``load`` and ``DOMContentLoaded`` events. Even if you where to load scripts in parallel they will probably get executed right before those events fire (..your page will still be rendered, it's just the trigger of the event) If you really want the scripts to load after those events, your gonna have to attach to those events, and then use Landon's solution to load your scripts after the events get triggered.